# Dynamic Table Name in Propel Query

Tags: php, propel

I am wondering if you can make the Table name of the propel query dynamic(sort of like a variable variable)? An example would be like \"DynamicVar"Query::create(). I have it working in ifs like in my example below, but could get rid of quite a few lines if made more dynamically. The tables are all setup the same, so they can be treated like the same object they just have different names.

Currently have something like this happening:

```
//$dynamic is a result of grabbing it from a different table 
//that corresponds to values passed by AJAX
$dyanmic = "Customer"
$query = null;
If( $dynamic == "Customer" ) $query = \CustomerQuery()::create();
If( $dynamic == something2 ) $query = \Table2Query()::create();
If( $dynamic == something3 ) $query = \Table3Query()::create();

If( $query != null ) {
   $query->filterBy("something");
   $query->find();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with the code some, and the code below will work for dynamically changing the table as long as each table can be treated like the same object. You can define your $table and use it in this fashion for a function that returns the object that you want

```
function Get_Table($table,$id){
    $query = null;
    $queryClass = '\\'. ucfirst($table) . 'Query';
        if ( class_exists( $queryClass ) ) {
            $$dynamics = $queryClass::create()
                ->filterById($id)
                ->find();

            if( $dynamics->getFirst() == null ) { return false; }
            /** @var \Base\.ucfirst($table) $dynamic*/
            $dynamic= $dynamics->getFirst();

            return $dynamic;
        }

        //On Failure
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```